# bash script finding if users are online

Tags: bash

I am trying to learn a simple script where you can check to see if a users is logged on. I am having problems setting variables correctly.

I would type the command `$ ./users (username)` and whatever is entered in user name should check `who` and see if there is a match. Here is my script below...

```
# function checks if user is online
function checkuser {
    for u in `who | cut -d" " -f1 | grep -qw $user`
    do
    if [ $u = $1 ]
    then
            echo "$1 is logged on"
    fi
    exit 0
}

# Checks if $1 is null or not
if [ -z $1 ]
then
    read user
else
    user=$1
fi

checkuser $u
exit 1
```

Comment: and the question is...

Comment: I am getting errors throughout

Comment: post the errors then :) By the way `grep -q` will output nothing

Comment: `line 15 syntax error near unexpected token `}'`

Comment: ah, you need parenthesis after the function name. See `man bash` for more details on how functions are declared

Comment: I saw the `grep -q` command somewhere online I thought that might have been correct. Your saying i need `function check user() {`

Comment: @markburk shellcheck says "Expected 'do'." which is more readable (after your update, "Couldn't find 'done' for this 'do'." ). Consider writing and testing single statements individually rather than trying to write a full script and then debugging a dozen issues at once.

Comment: ok I'm going to restart this file. That makes since...

Comment: @markburk sorry, scratch that, I misread the error and the documentation :( You don't need parenthesis if the keyword `function` is used

Comment: `checkuser $u`, should be `checkuser $user` (OR) `read user` and `user=$1` should be `read u` and `u=$1`. Good luck.